# Simulate a crash from a fetch with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, process, fetch, kill

I would like to know how to simulate a crash for a fetch.

For exemple I have this API LINK https://swapi.dev/api/people/1/?format=json and use I want to simulate a crash(kill) when fetching this API link. I would like to know how to do it with Node.js.

Comment: Just for testing, you could change the API LINK to something unreachable

Comment: Simulate a crash of what?  A crash of your server?

Comment: yes I'd like to crash the server

Comment: If you're running locally, you'll probably get a similar effect if you just used `http://localhost:9284` (where 9284 was just a random port). This port shouldn't be blocked by a firewall (because it's localhost), and nothing is listening on it (making it act the same as a server that crashed and stopped listening on its port).

Comment: Keep in mind that a server crash isn't the only thing that will prevent you from reaching the server. misconfiguring the server's firewall (or any other aspect of the server), the client losing internet, the SSL certificate expiring, etc.